# Subprocess Error when Launching ec2 cluster instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I am getting subprocess error when launching ec2 cluster instance.

The terminal lags on

> Waiting for cluster to enter 'ssh-ready' state'

when running

```
./spark-ec2 --key-pair=ru_spark --identity-file=ru_spark.pem --region=us-east-1 --zone=us-east-1a launch mycluster
```

Console:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-52-87-225-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com,52.87.225.32' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Connection to ec2-52-87-225-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com closed.
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-52-87-225-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com,52.87.225.32' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Transferring cluster's SSH key to slaves...
ec2-34-207-153-79.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-34-207-153-79.compute-1.amazonaws.com,34.207.153.79' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Cloning spark-ec2 scripts from https://github.com/amplab/spark-ec2/tree/branch-1.6 on master...
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-52-87-225-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com,52.87.225.32' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Cloning into 'spark-ec2'...
error: Peer reports incompatible or unsupported protocol version. while accessing https://github.com/amplab/spark-ec2/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
Connection to ec2-52-87-225-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com closed.
Error executing remote command, retrying after 30 seconds: Command '['ssh', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o', 'UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null', '-i', 'ru_spark.pem', '-t', '-t', u'root@ec2-52-87-225-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 'rm -rf spark-ec2 && git clone https://github.com/amplab/spark-ec2 -b branch-1.6 spark-ec2']' returned non-zero exit status 128
```

I updated to curl ssl, changed file permissions to 400 and 600 for ru_spark.pem but neither have helped solve the issue.

Comment: Try to update also `nss curl libcurl`

Comment: @TelinovDmitri, I ran ```brew install curl --with-openssl```, but not sure if there's macos equivalent of that ```nss curl libcurl```

Comment: You should update those on target instance where `git clone` occurs - Connection to ec2-52-87-225-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com closed. this is from your above logs